# Using a local PSOCK cluster with the new crew-workflow in targets

Tags: r, targets-r-package

I understand that the [recommended workflow](https://books.ropensci.org/targets/crew.html) for distributed computations in `targets` is via the `crew` package (built on `mirai`). I have successfully used crew to distribute work across multiple local cores using the following settings in my `_targets.R` file:

```r
tar_option_set(
  controller = crew_controller_local(workers = 7)
)
```

In previous projects I have distributed work across mutliple machines in a local network PSOCK cluster. Essentially, in my `_targets.R`, I set up the connection to the PSOCK cluster, create a `future`-plan, and run the pipeline using `tar_future_make()`.

```r
library("parallel")

cl <- makePSOCKcluster(...)

future::plan(future::cluster, workers = cl)
```

```r
targets::tar_make_future()
```

As of yet, I have been unable to set up a PSOCK cluster with `crew` to use it with `targets`. I have looked at the code in `crew` and `crew.cluster`, but I'm not making a lot of head way.

I understand that it's straight forward to create a PSOCK cluster with `mirai`, but I don't understand how to fit this with `crew`. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```r
library("mirai")

cl <- make_cluster(
  url = "tcp://local.host.ip.address"
  , remote = ssh_config(
    remotes = c("ssh://local.ip.address.1", "ssh://local.ip.address.2"),
    tunnel = FALSE
  )
)

parallel::parLapply(cl, iris, mean)

stop_cluster(cl)
```